# STM32 timers works wrong in pair

Tags: stm32, timer, interrupts

A few weeks ago I ran into some strange timer behavior that I couldn't figure out.

**Description**:
I have a system which count signal from a wheel with tooth (for synchronization), based on input signal I try to generate another signal at a certain point in time.
In attached chart I try to explain logic of my problem. Main timer setup as input capture (*rissing* edge) and work without any problem. Each tooth equal **10°**. So I try to generate signal which start on **16°** (toggle output pin HIGH) and end on **59°** (toggle output pin LOW).
After some calculations I know how much time it takes (*t1* and *t2* on chart, value for example).

[image: Simple explanation how it should work]

```
void TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler(void)
{
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&htim10, TIM_FLAG_CC1)) {

      /* Here some code with calculations, tooth count, deg count, timing count etc */

      // Check if start tooth reached (tooth_number * deg_per_tooth)
      if (my_struct.current_tooth * 10 == 10) {
       my_struct.polarity = 1;
       __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim11, my_struct.start_us); // start_us => t1 => 400
       (&htim11)->Instance->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_OPM | TIM_CR1_CEN;
      }

      // Check if end tooth reached (tooth_number * deg_per_tooth)
      if (my_struct.current_tooth * 10 == 50) {
        my_struct.polarity = 0;
        __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim11, my_struct.end_us); // end_us => t2 => 500
        (&htim11)->Instance->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_OPM | TIM_CR1_CEN;
      }

      my_struct.current_tooth++;
    }
  }
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim10);
}
```

Here handler fot TIM11 where I try toggle pin

```
void TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQHandler(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN TIM1_TRG_COM_TIM11_IRQn 0 */
  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&htim11, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE)) {
    if (my_struct.trigger.polarity == 1) {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(my_struct.GPIO_Port, my_struct.GPIO_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
    } else {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(my_struct.GPIO_Port, my_struct.GPIO_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
    }
    __HAL_TIM_CLEAR_FLAG(&htim11, TIM_FLAG_UPDATE);
  }
```

So in general, one timer (which count tooths) start another one which works in **OnePulseMode** with update interrupt.
**my_struct** defined as **volatile**

But in oscilloscope I see a completely opposite picture.

> t1 = 500us, and t2 = 400us

If I remove one of that timer based block of code, all work fine.
In example below I comment end signal, and the start delay was as expected => 400uS
It also works works viсe versa (if remove start_us handler)

```
void TIM1_UP_TIM10_IRQHandler(void)
{

  /* Here some code with calculations, tooth count, deg count, timing count etc */

  if (__HAL_TIM_GET_FLAG(&htim10, TIM_FLAG_CC1)) {

      // Check if start tooth reached (tooth_number * deg_per_tooth)
      if (my_struct.current_tooth * 10 == 10) {
       my_struct.polarity = 1;
       __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim11, my_struct.start_us); // start_us => t1 => 400
       (&htim11)->Instance->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_OPM | TIM_CR1_CEN;
      }

      // Check if end tooth reached (tooth_number * deg_per_tooth)
      if (my_struct.current_tooth * 10 == 50) {
        /* REMOVE IT */
        // my_struct.polarity = 0;
        // __HAL_TIM_SET_AUTORELOAD(&htim11, my_struct.end_us); // end_us => t2 => 500
        // (&htim11)->Instance->CR1 |= TIM_CR1_OPM | TIM_CR1_CEN;

        HAL_GPIO_WritePin(my_struct.GPIO_Port, my_struct.GPIO_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      }

      my_struct.current_tooth++;
    }
  }
  HAL_TIM_IRQHandler(&htim10);
}
```

I try to change timers, check what happens in registers, put static values (not calculated during work) - all time the same result.
Maybe I missed something, or I'm doing it wrong?
I would appreciate any help.
Tahnks